# how to give value of dropdown in controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

i have this code in codeigniter (section of form in codeigniter controller) :

```
$this->data['SalaryType'] = array(
    'name' => 'SalaryType',
    'id' => 'SalaryType',
    'type' => 'text',
    'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('SalaryType'),
);
$this->data['DefaultSalary'] = array(
   'name' => 'DefaultSalary',
   'id' => 'DefaultSalary',
   'type' => 'text',
   'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('DefaultSalary'),
);
$this->data['Salary_options'] = array(
    'language' => 'monthly',
    'world' => 'world'
);
```

(section of form in codeigniter view) :

```
  <p>
        Salary Type: <br />
        <?php echo form_dropdown($SalaryType,$Salary_options,'monthly');?>
  </p>

  <p>
        Default Salary: <br />
        <?php echo form_input($DefaultSalary);?>
  </p>
```

and i want use dropdown value but form send input value alone , and i can't access to dropdown value.
i check with `print_r($_POST);` but in post array observation 'DefaultSalary'.

Comment: May be your name attr of the drop down is not setting

Comment: thanks yes my correct code is : 
'form_dropdown('SalaryType',$Salary_options,'monthly');'

Comment: hey can i add id to my dropdown ?

Comment: if my comment solved your problem so kindly accpet my answer and give a vote upp :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized dropdown in wrong way

```
<?php echo form_dropdown($SalaryType,$Salary_options,'monthly');?>
```

use instead

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('DefaultSalary',$Salary_options,'language');?>
```

**1st parameter** is the name of the control

**2nd parameter** is the options array ->which is correct

**3rd parameter** is the selected **index** from the options array **not value** that can be in your case 'language' instead of 'monthly'

read [form_helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

And you will be able to access it using `$this->input->post('DefaultSalary');` and it will return the value of the option selected

Answer (score 1):

May be your name attr of the drop down is not setting...
For adding id to form_drop down you can try this..

```
form_dropdown('country', $options_array, '1','id="select_id"')
```

Note : this is not tested.